# Dnd или что делать с новым jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drag-n-drop

Есть задача: сделать Drag&Drop окно, которое будет принимать картинки с пк пользователя. Нашел классный пример. Но есть проблема: автор использует jquery 1.8, а у меня на проекте 3.1.1 - по этой причине `jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer');` не срабатывает, так как у `event` нет `props`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать?

```js
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

$(document).ready(function() {
 // В dataTransfer помещаются изображения которые перетащили в область div
 jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer');
 
 // Максимальное количество загружаемых изображений за одни раз
 var maxFiles = 6;
 
 // Оповещение по умолчанию
 var errMessage = 0;
 
 // Кнопка выбора файлов
 var defaultUploadBtn = $('#uploadbtn');
 
 // Массив для всех изображений
 var dataArray = [];
 
 // Область информер о загруженных изображениях - скрыта
 // $('#uploaded-files').hide();
 
 // Метод при падении файла в зону загрузки
 $('#drop-files').on('drop', function(e) {
  // Передаем в files все полученные изображения
  var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
  // Проверяем на максимальное количество файлов
  if (files.length <= maxFiles) {
   // Передаем массив с файлами в функцию загрузки на предпросмотр
   loadInView(files);
  } else {
   alert('Вы не можете загружать больше '+maxFiles+' изображений!'); 
   files.length = 0; return;
  }
 });
 
 // При нажатии на кнопку выбора файлов
 defaultUploadBtn.on('change', function() {
     // Заполняем массив выбранными изображениями
     var files = $(this)[0].files;
     // Проверяем на максимальное количество файлов
  if (files.length <= maxFiles) {
   // Передаем массив с файлами в функцию загрузки на предпросмотр
   loadInView(files);
   // Очищаем инпут файл путем сброса формы
            $('#frm').each(function(){
              this.reset();
   });
  } else {
   alert('Вы не можете загружать больше '+maxFiles+' изображений!'); 
   files.length = 0;
  }
 });
 
 // Функция загрузки изображений на предросмотр
 function loadInView(files) {
  // Показываем обасть предпросмотра
  $('#uploaded-holder').show();
  
  // Для каждого файла
  $.each(files, function(index, file) {
      
   // Несколько оповещений при попытке загрузить не изображение
   if (!files[index].type.match('image.*')) {
    
    if(errMessage == 0) {
     $('#drop-files p').html('Эй! только изображения!');
     ++errMessage
    }
    else if(errMessage == 1) {
     $('#drop-files p').html('Стоп! Загружаются только изображения!');
     ++errMessage
    }
    else if(errMessage == 2) {
     $('#drop-files p').html("Не умеешь читать? Только изображения!");
     ++errMessage
    }
    else if(errMessage == 3) {
     $('#drop-files p').html("Хорошо! Продолжай в том же духе");
     errMessage = 0;
    }
    return false;
   }
   
   // Проверяем количество загружаемых элементов
   if((dataArray.length+files.length) <= maxFiles) {
    // показываем область с кнопками
    $('#upload-button').css({'display' : 'block'});
   } 
   else { alert('Вы не можете загружать больше '+maxFiles+' изображений!'); return; }
   
   // Создаем новый экземпляра FileReader
   var fileReader = new FileReader();
    // Инициируем функцию FileReader
    fileReader.onload = (function(file) {
     
     return function(e) {
      // Помещаем URI изображения в массив
      dataArray.push({name : file.name, value : this.result});
      addImage((dataArray.length-1));
     }; 
      
    })(files[index]);
   // Производим чтение картинки по URI
   fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
  return false;
 }
  
 // Процедура добавления эскизов на страницу
 function addImage(ind) {
  // Если индекс отрицательный значит выводим весь массив изображений
  if (ind < 0 ) { 
  start = 0; end = dataArray.length; 
  } else {
  // иначе только определенное изображение 
  start = ind; end = ind+1; } 
  // Оповещения о загруженных файлах
  if(dataArray.length == 0) {
   // Если пустой массив скрываем кнопки и всю область
   $('#upload-button').hide();
   $('#uploaded-holder').hide();
  } else if (dataArray.length == 1) {
   $('#upload-button span').html("Был выбран 1 файл");
  } else {
   $('#upload-button span').html(dataArray.length+" файлов были выбраны");
  }
  // Цикл для каждого элемента массива
  for (i = start; i < end; i++) {
   // размещаем загруженные изображения
   if($('#dropped-files > .image').length <= maxFiles) { 
    $('#dropped-files').append('<div id="img-'+i+'" class="image" style="background: url('+dataArray[i].value+'); background-size: cover;"> <a href="#" id="drop-'+i+'" class="drop-button">Удалить изображение</a></div>'); 
   }
  }
  return false;
 }
 
 // Функция удаления всех изображений
 function restartFiles() {
 
  // Установим бар загрузки в значение по умолчанию
  $('#loading-bar .loading-color').css({'width' : '0%'});
  $('#loading').css({'display' : 'none'});
  $('#loading-content').html(' ');
  
  // Удаляем все изображения на странице и скрываем кнопки
  $('#upload-button').hide();
  $('#dropped-files > .image').remove();
  $('#uploaded-holder').hide();
 
  // Очищаем массив
  dataArray.length = 0;
  
  return false;
 }
 
 // Удаление только выбранного изображения 
 $("#dropped-files").on("click","a[id^='drop']", function() {
  // получаем название id
   var elid = $(this).attr('id');
  // создаем массив для разделенных строк
  var temp = new Array();
  // делим строку id на 2 части
  temp = elid.split('-');
  // получаем значение после тире тоесть индекс изображения в массиве
  dataArray.splice(temp[1],1);
  // Удаляем старые эскизы
  $('#dropped-files > .image').remove();
  // Обновляем эскизи в соответсвии с обновленным массивом
  addImage(-1);  
 });
 
 // Удалить все изображения кнопка 
 $('#dropped-files #upload-button .delete').click(restartFiles);
 
 // Загрузка изображений на сервер
 $('#upload-button .upload').click(function() {
  
  // Показываем прогресс бар
  $("#loading").show();
  // переменные для работы прогресс бара
  var totalPercent = 100 / dataArray.length;
  var x = 0;
  
  $('#loading-content').html('Загружен '+dataArray[0].name);
  // Для каждого файла
  $.each(dataArray, function(index, file) { 
   // загружаем страницу и передаем значения, используя HTTP POST запрос 
   $.post('upload.php', dataArray[index], function(data) {
   
    var fileName = dataArray[index].name;
    ++x;
    
    // Изменение бара загрузки
    $('#loading-bar .loading-color').css({'width' : totalPercent*(x)+'%'});
    // Если загрузка закончилась
    if(totalPercent*(x) == 100) {
     // Загрузка завершена
     $('#loading-content').html('Загрузка завершена!');
     
     // Вызываем функцию удаления всех изображений после задержки 1 секунда
     setTimeout(restartFiles, 1000);
    // если еще продолжается загрузка 
    } else if(totalPercent*(x) < 100) {
     // Какой файл загружается
     $('#loading-content').html('Загружается '+fileName);
    }
    
    // Формируем в виде списка все загруженные изображения
    // data формируется в upload.php
    var dataSplit = data.split(':');
    if(dataSplit[1] == 'загружен успешно') {
     $('#uploaded-files').append('<li><a href="images/'+dataSplit[0]+'">'+fileName+'</a> загружен успешно</li>');
        
    } else {
     $('#uploaded-files').append('<li><a href="images/'+data+'. Имя файла: '+dataArray[index].name+'</li>');
    }
    
   });
  });
  // Показываем список загруженных файлов
  $('#uploaded-files').show();
  return false;
 });
 
 // Простые стили для области перетаскивания
 $('#drop-files').on('dragenter', function() {
  $(this).css({'box-shadow' : 'inset 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)', 'border' : '4px dashed #bb2b2b'});
  return false;
 });
 
 $('#drop-files').on('drop', function() {
  $(this).css({'box-shadow' : 'none', 'border' : '4px dashed rgba(0,0,0,0.2)'});
  return false;
 });
});
```

```css
.content {
 margin-top:80px;
 padding: 20px;
}
#drop-files {
 position:relative;
 width: 500px;
 height: 140px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 border-radius: 10px;
 border: 4px dashed rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 padding-top:80px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 2em;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#drop-files p {
 clear:none;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}

#uploaded-holder {
 display: none;
 position:relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#dropped-files {
 display:block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 950px;
}

#upload-button {
 z-index: 9999;
 display: none;
 margin: 20px 0;
}

.drop-button {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 9999;
 padding: 5px;
 width: 100%;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 font-size: 1em;
 bottom: 0;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #FFF;
}

#dropped-files .image {
 position: relative;
 height: 200px;
 width: 300px;
 border: 4px solid #fff;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 background: #fff;
 float: left;
 border-radius: 4px;
 margin: 0 7px 7px 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#upload-button .ss-upload {
 font-size: 0.7em;
}

#upload-button a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: bold;
 box-shadow: 0 0 1000px 62px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), inset 0 -35px 40px -10px #0A9FCA;
 font-size: 20px;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 background-color: #4bc1e3;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

#upload-button span {
 position:relative;
 text-align: center;
 background: white;
 border-radius: 10px;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 padding: 6px;
 margin-right: 8px;
}
#upload-button a:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 0 1000px 62px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), inset 0 -5px 40px 0px #0A9FCA; 
}


#dropped-files #upload-button .delete {
 padding: 7px 6px 4px 6px;
 border-radius: 100px;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 box-shadow: none;
 font-size: 1em;
 margin-left: 8px;
}

#dropped-files #upload-button .delete:hover {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

#loading {
 display: none;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 margin: 20px;
}

#loading-bar {
 width: 404px;
 height: 40px;
 background: #fff;
 box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 2px;
}

.loading-color {
 width: 0%;
 height: 100%;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
 -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
 -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
 -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
 transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
 border-radius: inherit;
 background-color: #4edbf1;
}

#loading-content {
 position: relative;
 top: 15px;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 width: 405px;
}

#file-name-holder {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
}

#file-name-holder h1 {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 20px 0;
 font-size: 3em;
 margin: 0;
}

#uploaded-files {
 width:500px;
 list-style:none;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding: 10px;
 color: #545454;
}

#uploaded-files li {
 padding: 10px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 25px;
 color: #545454;
}

#uploaded-files a {
 color: #1bacbf;
}
.main {
 width:900px;
 margin:0 auto;
 height:100%;
 margin-top:100px;
}
.main img {
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 width:280px;
 height:180px;
 margin:10px;
}
a.nav { 
 font-family:tahoma;
 font-size:20px;
 color:#4280af;
 text-decoration:none;
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
a.nav:hover {
    color:#fffb89;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
 <center><a href="gallery.php" class="nav">Перейти в галерею</a></center>
 <!-- Область для перетаскивания -->
 <div id="drop-files" ondragover="return false">
  <p>Перетащите изображение сюда</p>
        <form id="frm">
         <input type="file" id="uploadbtn" multiple />
        </form>
 </div>
    <!-- Область предпросмотра -->
 <div id="uploaded-holder"> 
  <div id="dropped-files">
         <!-- Кнопки загрузить и удалить, а также количество файлов -->
         <div id="upload-button">
             <center>
                 <span>0 Файлов</span>
     <a href="#" class="upload">Загрузить</a>
     <a href="#" class="delete">Удалить</a>
                    <!-- Прогресс бар загрузки -->
                 <div id="loading">
      <div id="loading-bar">
       <div class="loading-color"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="loading-content"></div>
     </div>
                </center>
   </div>
        </div>
 </div>
 <!-- Список загруженных файлов -->
 <div id="file-name-holder">
  <ul id="uploaded-files">
   <h1>Загруженные файлы</h1>
  </ul>
 </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы у вас на новых версиях jQuery работали плагины под старые версии, используйте [jQuery Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate):

```js
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

$(document).ready(function() {
  // В dataTransfer помещаются изображения которые перетащили в область div
  jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer');

  // Максимальное количество загружаемых изображений за одни раз
  var maxFiles = 6;

  // Оповещение по умолчанию
  var errMessage = 0;

  // Кнопка выбора файлов
  var defaultUploadBtn = $('#uploadbtn');

  // Массив для всех изображений
  var dataArray = [];

  // Область информер о загруженных изображениях - скрыта
  // $('#uploaded-files').hide();

  // Метод при падении файла в зону загрузки
  $('#drop-files').on('drop', function(e) {
    // Передаем в files все полученные изображения
    var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    // Проверяем на максимальное количество файлов
    if (files.length <= maxFiles) {
      // Передаем массив с файлами в функцию загрузки на предпросмотр
      loadInView(files);
    } else {
      alert('Вы не можете загружать больше ' + maxFiles + ' изображений!');
      files.length = 0;
      return;
    }
  });

  // При нажатии на кнопку выбора файлов
  defaultUploadBtn.on('change', function() {
    // Заполняем массив выбранными изображениями
    var files = $(this)[0].files;
    // Проверяем на максимальное количество файлов
    if (files.length <= maxFiles) {
      // Передаем массив с файлами в функцию загрузки на предпросмотр
      loadInView(files);
      // Очищаем инпут файл путем сброса формы
      $('#frm').each(function() {
        this.reset();
      });
    } else {
      alert('Вы не можете загружать больше ' + maxFiles + ' изображений!');
      files.length = 0;
    }
  });

  // Функция загрузки изображений на предросмотр
  function loadInView(files) {
    // Показываем обасть предпросмотра
    $('#uploaded-holder').show();

    // Для каждого файла
    $.each(files, function(index, file) {

      // Несколько оповещений при попытке загрузить не изображение
      if (!files[index].type.match('image.*')) {

        if (errMessage == 0) {
          $('#drop-files p').html('Эй! только изображения!');
          ++errMessage
        } else if (errMessage == 1) {
          $('#drop-files p').html('Стоп! Загружаются только изображения!');
          ++errMessage
        } else if (errMessage == 2) {
          $('#drop-files p').html("Не умеешь читать? Только изображения!");
          ++errMessage
        } else if (errMessage == 3) {
          $('#drop-files p').html("Хорошо! Продолжай в том же духе");
          errMessage = 0;
        }
        return false;
      }

      // Проверяем количество загружаемых элементов
      if ((dataArray.length + files.length) <= maxFiles) {
        // показываем область с кнопками
        $('#upload-button').css({
          'display': 'block'
        });
      } else {
        alert('Вы не можете загружать больше ' + maxFiles + ' изображений!');
        return;
      }

      // Создаем новый экземпляра FileReader
      var fileReader = new FileReader();
      // Инициируем функцию FileReader
      fileReader.onload = (function(file) {

        return function(e) {
          // Помещаем URI изображения в массив
          dataArray.push({
            name: file.name,
            value: this.result
          });
          addImage((dataArray.length - 1));
        };

      })(files[index]);
      // Производим чтение картинки по URI
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
    return false;
  }

  // Процедура добавления эскизов на страницу
  function addImage(ind) {
    // Если индекс отрицательный значит выводим весь массив изображений
    if (ind < 0) {
      start = 0;
      end = dataArray.length;
    } else {
      // иначе только определенное изображение 
      start = ind;
      end = ind + 1;
    }
    // Оповещения о загруженных файлах
    if (dataArray.length == 0) {
      // Если пустой массив скрываем кнопки и всю область
      $('#upload-button').hide();
      $('#uploaded-holder').hide();
    } else if (dataArray.length == 1) {
      $('#upload-button span').html("Был выбран 1 файл");
    } else {
      $('#upload-button span').html(dataArray.length + " файлов были выбраны");
    }
    // Цикл для каждого элемента массива
    for (i = start; i < end; i++) {
      // размещаем загруженные изображения
      if ($('#dropped-files > .image').length <= maxFiles) {
        $('#dropped-files').append('<div id="img-' + i + '" class="image" style="background: url(' + dataArray[i].value + '); background-size: cover;"> <a href="#" id="drop-' + i + '" class="drop-button">Удалить изображение</a></div>');
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  // Функция удаления всех изображений
  function restartFiles() {

    // Установим бар загрузки в значение по умолчанию
    $('#loading-bar .loading-color').css({
      'width': '0%'
    });
    $('#loading').css({
      'display': 'none'
    });
    $('#loading-content').html(' ');

    // Удаляем все изображения на странице и скрываем кнопки
    $('#upload-button').hide();
    $('#dropped-files > .image').remove();
    $('#uploaded-holder').hide();

    // Очищаем массив
    dataArray.length = 0;

    return false;
  }

  // Удаление только выбранного изображения 
  $("#dropped-files").on("click", "a[id^='drop']", function() {
    // получаем название id
    var elid = $(this).attr('id');
    // создаем массив для разделенных строк
    var temp = new Array();
    // делим строку id на 2 части
    temp = elid.split('-');
    // получаем значение после тире тоесть индекс изображения в массиве
    dataArray.splice(temp[1], 1);
    // Удаляем старые эскизы
    $('#dropped-files > .image').remove();
    // Обновляем эскизи в соответсвии с обновленным массивом
    addImage(-1);
  });

  // Удалить все изображения кнопка 
  $('#dropped-files #upload-button .delete').click(restartFiles);

  // Загрузка изображений на сервер
  $('#upload-button .upload').click(function() {

    // Показываем прогресс бар
    $("#loading").show();
    // переменные для работы прогресс бара
    var totalPercent = 100 / dataArray.length;
    var x = 0;

    $('#loading-content').html('Загружен ' + dataArray[0].name);
    // Для каждого файла
    $.each(dataArray, function(index, file) {
      // загружаем страницу и передаем значения, используя HTTP POST запрос 
      $.post('upload.php', dataArray[index], function(data) {

        var fileName = dataArray[index].name;
        ++x;

        // Изменение бара загрузки
        $('#loading-bar .loading-color').css({
          'width': totalPercent * (x) + '%'
        });
        // Если загрузка закончилась
        if (totalPercent * (x) == 100) {
          // Загрузка завершена
          $('#loading-content').html('Загрузка завершена!');

          // Вызываем функцию удаления всех изображений после задержки 1 секунда
          setTimeout(restartFiles, 1000);
          // если еще продолжается загрузка 
        } else if (totalPercent * (x) < 100) {
          // Какой файл загружается
          $('#loading-content').html('Загружается ' + fileName);
        }

        // Формируем в виде списка все загруженные изображения
        // data формируется в upload.php
        var dataSplit = data.split(':');
        if (dataSplit[1] == 'загружен успешно') {
          $('#uploaded-files').append('<li><a href="images/' + dataSplit[0] + '">' + fileName + '</a> загружен успешно</li>');

        } else {
          $('#uploaded-files').append('<li><a href="images/' + data + '. Имя файла: ' + dataArray[index].name + '</li>');
        }

      });
    });
    // Показываем список загруженных файлов
    $('#uploaded-files').show();
    return false;
  });

  // Простые стили для области перетаскивания
  $('#drop-files').on('dragenter', function() {
    $(this).css({
      'box-shadow': 'inset 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
      'border': '4px dashed #bb2b2b'
    });
    return false;
  });

  $('#drop-files').on('drop', function() {
    $(this).css({
      'box-shadow': 'none',
      'border': '4px dashed rgba(0,0,0,0.2)'
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  margin-top: 80px;
  padding: 20px;
}

#drop-files {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 4px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding-top: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#drop-files p {
  clear: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#uploaded-holder {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#dropped-files {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 950px;
}

#upload-button {
  z-index: 9999;
  display: none;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.drop-button {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  font-size: 1em;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #FFF;
}

#dropped-files .image {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 7px 7px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#upload-button .ss-upload {
  font-size: 0.7em;
}

#upload-button a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1000px 62px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), inset 0 -35px 40px -10px #0A9FCA;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #4bc1e3;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#upload-button span {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  padding: 6px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

#upload-button a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1000px 62px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), inset 0 -5px 40px 0px #0A9FCA;
}

#dropped-files #upload-button .delete {
  padding: 7px 6px 4px 6px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

#dropped-files #upload-button .delete:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

#loading {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
}

#loading-bar {
  width: 404px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
}

.loading-color {
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background-color: #4edbf1;
}

#loading-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  width: 405px;
}

#file-name-holder {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#file-name-holder h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin: 0;
}

#uploaded-files {
  width: 500px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #545454;
}

#uploaded-files li {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #545454;
}

#uploaded-files a {
  color: #1bacbf;
}

.main {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.main img {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 280px;
  height: 180px;
  margin: 10px;
}

a.nav {
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #4280af;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

a.nav:hover {
  color: #fffb89;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/3.0.0/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <center><a href="gallery.php" class="nav">Перейти в галерею</a></center>
  <!-- Область для перетаскивания -->
  <div id="drop-files" ondragover="return false">
    <p>Перетащите изображение сюда</p>
    <form id="frm">
      <input type="file" id="uploadbtn" multiple />
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- Область предпросмотра -->
  <div id="uploaded-holder">
    <div id="dropped-files">
      <!-- Кнопки загрузить и удалить, а также количество файлов -->
      <div id="upload-button">
        <center>
          <span>0 Файлов</span>
          <a href="#" class="upload">Загрузить</a>
          <a href="#" class="delete">Удалить</a>
          <!-- Прогресс бар загрузки -->
          <div id="loading">
            <div id="loading-bar">
              <div class="loading-color"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="loading-content"></div>
          </div>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Список загруженных файлов -->
  <div id="file-name-holder">
    <ul id="uploaded-files">
      <h1>Загруженные файлы</h1>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое все заработало=)