# Своя кнопка загрузки файлов

Tags: css3, html5

Здравствуйте. Скажите, возможно ли сделать то, что на фото, средствами css3 и html5. Если нет, то в каком направлении двигаться, чтобы воплотить это в жизнь?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Без JavaScript на одних лишь html/css не удастся. Вот пример: http://www.dropzonejs.com – исходники открыты к изучению...

Comment: Прочитай про drag and drop input file, вопрос сам собой отпадёт.

Comment: Вот, отличный пример: https://css-tricks.com/drag-and-drop-file-uploading/

Comment: @rugabarbo, ответ не верный, можно.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов, дайте пример реализации без JS, пожалуйста.

Comment: Только CSS+HTML: https://codepen.io/TheLukasWeb/pen/qlGDa

Comment: вот здесь посмотри http://demo.dotnetawesome.com/drag-drop-file-upload-aspnet-mvc

Comment: @AresGod, если мы не собираемся отображать загруженные файлы в этом поле после загрузки, то да, можно. Но получится очень нефункциональное поле загрузки. Стилизовать на html/css можно всё, что угодно, под любой внешний вид, но как только речь заходит про функциональность – их становится недостаточно. А к полям загрузки файлов обычно предъявляются очень высокие функциональные требования (отображение загруженных файлов, возможность удалять, сортировка, повторное отображение уже загруженных и т.д.).

Comment: @rugabarbo я согласен. Это максимум, что можно сделать на html+css. Выше скинул отличный пример with JS.

Comment: Возвожно, вам поможет пример из этого ответа - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/715159/209956

Comment: @rugabarbo https://css-tricks.com/examples/DragAndDropFileUploading/ тут Js, используется только для браузера и не нужных функций, я бы сам написал, но с телефона. Да, html+CSS не даст миниатюр картинок, но они и не к чему, если объектов 11 допустим

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов, дело не в миниатюрах. Без JS Вы добъётесь **только стилизации** поля загрузки, но **не функциональности**, потому что html/css не предоставляет полного инструментария для работы с upload-событиями.

Comment: Input file, даст на все возможно, вплоть до drag and Drop.